# Revelation Space question about "Nostalgia for Infinity" - what is their purpose?

Tags: alastair-reynolds, revelation-space

So I'm reading this and wondering... are these guys on some kind of mission... are they a clan or workers for some company? Are they a family? I don't understand their purpose/motivation. I know they want to cure their captain of some kind of nanotech virus. But why are they even in space? do they make money from working in space... Appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe it was ever mentioned. Like most Ultranauts, they likely hauled cargo between star systems. Lighthuggers have an enormous cargo capacity, as displayed when

> the lighthugger *Nostalgia for Infinity* transported 160,000 people from the planet Resurgam.

Perhaps the crew of *Nostalgia for Infinity* had interest in black market military hardware, as they went through a great deal of trouble stealing, cracking, and test-firing the Conjoiner [cache weapons](https://revelationspace.fandom.com/wiki/Cache_Weapons).
(The cache weapons were stolen *before* the Melding Plague, suggesting Captain Brannigan was behind the operation.)